# Choosing Screw Terminals for connecting Arduino to other components

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, relay, screw-terminal

For connecting a 16 channel relay board to 16 devices running off 24VDC, and for connecting the relay board to Arduino, I am thinking of using screw terminals where one side of the terminals connect to the relay board's screw terminals, while the other side of the terminals connect to 24V devices.

Would using pairs of [screw terminal block like the one shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmm3O.png) and [the one shown here](https://www.oscsys.com/blog/1001955) be suitable? 2 pairs of these blocks will connect Arduino to relay board, and 2 pairs will connect relay board to the devices they are controlling.

[image]

[image]

Would these be recommended for my use?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The part you show in your question doesn't fit Arduino's connectors directly. Also notice that the space between the Arduino board connectors is non-standard pitch, giving you a hard time trying to fit a normal protoboard on the Arduino.

I personally like these [ScrewShields](http://wingshieldindustries.com/products/screwshield/) for use with Arduino.

[image]

There are more variations, some are useful for the extended number of GPIO on MEGA,

[image]

Although I'm not sure how to route the attached wires at the inner row at the right end. There must be alternatives that circumvent this issue.

[some have a prototyping area](http://www.gravitech.us/screwshieldv15.html)

[image]
 ...

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of adding an additional screw terminal block between the Arduino and the relay board so they do not connect to each other directly. Is this common practice, and what kind of screw terminal blocks should I be using?

Comment: Updated question with a sketch of what I'm trying to connect together. Probably looking for a kind of terminal block where one device connects to one side of it, another device connects to the opposite side. Maybe they are called DIN Rail Terminal Blocks?